# Powershell: get-date & [datetime]::FromFileTime returns different values

Tags: powershell

Why does get-date & [datetime]::FromFileTime returns different values when converting FileTime? An example:

```
Get-Date 129442497539436142
```

returns Thursday, March 10, 0411 4:55:53 PM, but

```
[datetime]::FromFileTime("129442497539436142")
```

returns Thursday, March 10, 2011 11:55:53 AM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They produce the same result for me, presumably because I'm in GMT.

(FromFileTime parses the time as [UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx), Get-Date appears to be using your local time.)

Answer (score 4):

FileTimes are so-called Ticks. 10 million pass every second. Filetime are 0 at midnight, *January 1st 1601* (UTC).

Get-date also have ticks, but the base of ticks used by Get-Date is NOT 1601.
It is *January 1st year 1*.
You can basically identify the 2 different types of ticks by the first digit.

Filetime ticks starts with digit **1** in the rough range of -100 to + 200 years from now.

The ticks using base on January 1st year 0 starts with **6** in roughly the same time range...

In PowerShell you can get verify Jan. 1st year 1 is tick 0 by typing:

```
[datetime]'0001-01-01' | Select-Object -property Ticks
```

Answer (score 3):

Get-Date get ticks from 01/01/0001 00:00

[datetime]::FromFileTimeUTC($a) get ticks from 01/01/1601 00:00

You wrote:

```
returns Thursday, March 10, 0411 4:55:53 PM, but
returns Thursday, March 10, 2011 11:55:53 AM
```

The difference is 1600 years

This is an example:

```
$a = ([datetime]::Now).Ticks - ([DateTime]("01/01/0001 00:00")).Ticks
Get-Date $a # get ticks from 01/01/0001 00:00
$a = ([datetime]::Now).Ticks - ([datetime]("01/01/1601 00:00")).Ticks
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUTC($a) # get ticks from 01/01/1601 00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

It is based on your local "long date" format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqgU7.png)

Either you have to change your system "Long Date"

(OR) Use below command

(get-date).tostring("dd/MM/yyyy")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfEea.png)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

Regards,
Manikandan Boopathy